# Delay in redirection causes a temporary display of incorrect components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Experiencing issues where I want to redirect the page based on a logic.

So if I redirect, should just go to the page I am redirecting and not show the components within `MyComponent`.

The redirect does occur but there is a delay like 1 - 2 second.

During this period, there is a display of the component when it shouldn't.

Is there a way to prevent this and just redirect?

Note: This component has been minimised to focus on the issue. Actual component has a lot more going on in there.

The issue can be observed in this minimal project.
https://github.com/kvaithin/react-routing-issue

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  // just a temp call to emulate getting data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=react")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((d) => setData(d));
  }, []);

  // i want this redirect to happen without seeing the text below.
  useEffect(() => {
    const redirect = true;
    if (redirect) {
      // some other logic that will determine if redirect = true
      window.location.replace("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      I should never reach here cos of the redirect But I still see this text briefly for a second
      or 2 before redirecting.
      {/* other components inside here  */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*"The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen"*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). If you want to prevent the content to be shown before you excute your logic, you could use a `checking` state like so:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [checking, setChecking] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=react")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((d) => setData(d));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const redirect = true;
    if (redirect) {
      setChecking(false);
      window.location.replace("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux");
    }
  }, []);

  if (checking) return null; // or a loading message or component

  return (
    <div>
      I should never reach here cos of the redirect But I still see this text briefly for a second
      or 2 before redirecting.
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```